# javascript button target_blank?

Tags: javascript

I have a button that links to a website, but i want it to open in a new window. I know its probably a dumb question but i am very new to javascript. Below is my code. it works but opens in the same window. I have tried a few things and they just arent working

```
<input type="button" value="eStore"

               onclick="location='www.google.com'" 
                style="width: 88px; text-align: center;" />
```

is there a way to make it targt_blank to open in a new window? Please and thank you.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+open+new+window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
<input type="button" value="eStore"
 onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/','_blank')"
 style="width: 88px; text-align: center;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to have a look at the `window.open(URL)` method, rather than changing the location.

Comment: yes i think that is exactly what i need but where do i put that in my code? like i said i am very new to this. i tried it once already and didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onclick="javascript:window.open('www.google.com');"
```

Comment: Why have you added a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) to that statement?